# Log4j2: not write into file

Tags: java, log4j2

I added Log4j2 into my project

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
```

and added next properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n%xwEx"/>
            <!-- Крутое, но бесцветное логирование-->
<!--            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36}.%M():%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}"/>-->
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="C:/Users/Mi/output.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j.filelogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

App write logs to console, but not in file. As I wait, app shall write logs into file by url `C:/Users/Mi/output.log`, it creates automatically, I can't delete it while app is wotking, but there no logs. Please advice, what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only logging stuff from `org.apache.logging.log4j.filelogger` package into the "File" appender. The Logger name property is the package/class reference

You should do something like this to get logging to file instead of console:

```
<Root level="info">
    <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
</Root>
```

If you want console and file do:

```
<Root level="info">
    <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Root>
```